# Bus error - What's wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, bus, bus-error

```
long int d[500], i;
d[1] = 1;
d[2] = 2;
d[3] = 4;
for(i = 4; i<=500; i++)
    d[i] = d[i-1] + d[i-2] + d[i-3];

int n = 500;
printf("%ld\n", d[500]);
```

The compiler is gcc. Bus error occurred at compiling. What caused this to happen?

Comment: Arrays are zero-based.  Meaning the first element is always at the 0th position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`long int d[500]` declares an array with 500 items indexed from `0` to `499`

`d[500]` is outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: Oh, this is really embarrassing...It's the first time I come into bus error and didn't even think of checking array boundary...

Comment: The root cause is the out of bounds access inside the loop because it precedes the access in `printf`. what happens after the first out of bounds access is pretty much pointless. The program ceased to be a valid program when the first UB occured.

Comment: I'm referring to any access to d[500], in the loop or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%ld\n", d[500]);` - accessing beyond the array.

`d[i] = d[i-1] + d[i-2] + d[i-3];` - accessing beyond the array.

Comment: ...and so does assignment to `d[i]` in the for loop with `i<=500`

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: And that is the root cause because it precedes the access in `printf`. Basically the UB happened during the loop and hence what happens after is pretty much pointless. The program ceased to be a valid program when the first UB occured.

Comment: Thanks. I should not have ignored such a beginner mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
long int d[500];
....
for(i = 4; i<=500; i++)
            ^^^^^^
```

You wrote passed the bounds of allocated memory resulting in **Undefined behavior**.
You are supposed to access array elements only from index `0` to `499` because that is what you allocated.

Comment: Thanks... I should have noticed that... It's the first time I got bus error so I didn't mention to check array boundary...

Comment: @CDT: I am going to repeat this for the third time here: *The root cause is the out of bounds access inside the loop because it precedes the access in `printf`. what happens after the first out of bounds access is pretty much pointless. The program ceased to be a valid program when the first UB occured.*

Answer (score 0):

`long int d[500]` gives you the memory for `500` long digit integers and are assigned for `d[0]` to `d[499]` but you are calling `d[500]` whose value is not defined.